# INSERT to table not working. Using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, insert

I have two scripts which insert a new line into my SQL database. One works, and the other doesn't. They both look the same (but for the different data) but one doesn't work. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Disclosure: I am self taught and have not taken any programming courses except for a pascal class several years ago.

This one works:
    include('db.php');

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO leadprofile (first_name, last_name, home_phone, mobile_phone, work_phone, work_phone_ext, email_address, description, fk_source) VALUES ('$_POST[first_name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[home_phone]','$_POST[mobile_phone]','$_POST[work_phone]','$_POST[work_phone_ext]','$_POST[email_address]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[fk_source]')");

mysql_close($con);
```

This one does not work. The page loads, but no values are inserted into the table:

```
include('db.php');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tasks (fk_lead_id, task_type, task_detail, due_date) VALUES ('$_POST[fk_lead_id]',('$_POST[task_type]','$_POST[task_detail]','$_POST[due_date]')");

mysql_close($con);
```

Both are referencing the same db.php file which loads the database only. I appreciate any help and hope it is something crazy simple. I have confirmed the table name and column names are all correct.

Comment: And any errors that you're not trapping; unescaped strings (what if my surname is `O'Connor`?); SQL injection risks?

Comment: Do not use mysql_ functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli_ or PDO instead. Also NEVER pass any kind of input directly into a SQL query, look up SQL injections asap.

Comment: Where are all these awful mysql tutorials that make no mention of mysql_error()? "I am self taught" - Forget everything you know and start over http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Mike B I will go to study phptherightway.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a bracket too much

```
INSERT INTO tasks (fk_lead_id, task_type, task_detail, due_date)
    VALUES ('$_POST[fk_lead_id]',('$_POST[task_type]','$_POST[task_detail]','$_POST[due_date]')
                                 ^here
```

You would have easily found out if you had used `mysql_error()` e.g. like the following:

```
mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I ran the or die(mysql_error()); and realized in addition to the extra bracket I had a space in the column name in the table itself on the database. Thanks for pointing out what or die(mysql_error()); does. Case closed and this is working now.